# Setting default button for panel affects other buttons when they are in focus and Enter is pressed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I my ASP.NET application i have used panel and have set the default button property to proceed to next page.
Consider a scenario where the user navigates to the previous page button using tab and then clicks enter then on pressing the ENTER button the default property comes into play and user proceeds to the next page.

Is there any way we can make the previous button click.

```
<asp:Panel ID="panel" runat="server" DefaultButton="NextButton">
 <....Some Other ASP Controls....>
<asp:Button ID="PreviousButton" runat="server" Text="GotoPreviousPage" />
<asp:Button ID="NextButton" runat="server" Text="GotoNextPage" />
```

When I navigate to Previous button using the keyboard tab and when previous button is in focus and I hit ENTER then NextButton is getting called due to the default button property.
As the defaultButton Property is called whenever within the panel Enter key is pressed. Hence i want a functionality that when the focus is on another button and i hit enter default property should not work.
I tried changing the default property on PreviousButton click:-

```
<asp:Button ID="PreviousButton" runat="server" OnClientClick=<%=panel.DefaultButton="PreviousButton"%> Text="GotoPreviousPage" />
```

Comment: Can you post example code?

Comment: It's not clear. Explain better and post code sample, please.